# Find element in a vector and remove it

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a vector with a set of pointers to edges in a graph. 
I'm supposed to remove an edge but i get an error when i run this code. What i try to do is to find the index of the edge I'm looking for so i can delete the edge from the list.

Error:

```
error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Edge**,    
std::vector<Edge*> >' to 'int' in initialization
   int i = find(edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(), *e);
```

I understand it has something to do with the convertion from Edge To int, but i cant find the soloution for this.

My method:

```
void Graph::removeEdge(Edge *e)
{

Node* v = e->endpoint[0];
Node* w = e->endpoint[1];
if (this->areAdjacent(v,w) == true)
{
  int i = find(edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(), *e);

  edgeList.erase(i)

 }
}
```

Graph Class

```
class Graph : public GraphADT {

public:
// General graph methods
Node* aVertex();
void insertVertex(Node* n);
void insertEdge(Node* v, Node* w, int i = 0);
void removeVertex(Node* n);
void removeEdge(Edge* e);
std::vector<Edge*>& incidentEdges(Node* n);
Node** endVertices(Edge* e);
Node* opposite(Node* n, Edge* e);
bool areAdjacent(Node* v, Node* w);

// Methods for directed edges
bool isDirected(Edge* e);
void insertDirectedEdge(Node* v, Node* w, int i = 0);
Node* origin(Edge* e);
Node* destination(Edge* e);

// Generic methods
int numVertices();
int numEdges();
vector<Node*>& vertices();
vector<Edge*>& edges();

// Algorithms
void depthFirstTraversal(Node* n);
void breadthFirstTraversal(Node* n);
vector<Edge*> primsAlgorithm();
void dijkstrasAlgorithm(Node* n);

private:
void setAllUnvisited();
vector<Node*> verticeList;
vector<Edge*> edgeList;
};
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Replace `int i` by `auto i` (that you can rename into `it` as **iterator**).

Comment: it seems also that `*e` should just be `e` in the `find`.

Comment: added my graph methods. I can't find a way to delete an edge without my program crashing. (silent, no errors this time).

Comment: Try to add `if (it != edgeList.end()) ` before `edgeList.erase(it)`

Comment: Nah, actually, it seems that the iterator is not finding the edge. I will get to the end of the list when i should'nt, - and my program crash when i try to erase.

Answer (score 2):

`std::find` [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) returns not an `int`, but `iterator`. You could use `auto` keyword, as mentioned in comments, or use something like

```
std::vector<Edge*>::iterator it = find(edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(), e);
```

Also you should check `iterator` before erase

```
void Graph::removeEdge(Edge *e)
{
  Node* v = e->endpoint[0];
  Node* w = e->endpoint[1];
  if (this->areAdjacent(v,w))
  {
    auto it = find(edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(), e);

    if ( it != edgeList.end() )
      edgeList.erase(it)
  }
}
```

because invalid input causes [undefined behavior](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).

Comment: It still crashes when i get to the erase-part. I assume it should be erase(it) and not erase(i) since "i" is not declared.

Comment: @KimR Yes, it should be `it`, sorry for my mistake